# Deprecated compiling error

Tags: java, compilation, javac, deprecated

I'm trying to compile my Java program, however I am getting a "Deprecated File" error.

I normally compile the file by typing "Javac FileName.java", however I get an error saying:

> FileName.java  uses or overrides a depreacted API.
>   Recompile with Xlint-deprecation for details.

What do I type into the command line to make it run?

Comment: "Recompile with Xlint-deprecation for details."

Comment: But how do i "Recompile with Xlint-deprecation"?! – Tom Stock just now edit

Comment: Tom, you don't need to do it, it's just a warning. You'd be better off viewing the deprecated issues in your IDE than here. In short, you will still get a class file. Check the output path and it's there.

Comment: But why wont it run, if it's just a warning?

Comment: Iv just realised how stupid ive been, thanks guys..

Comment: I hope I answered your query. It *will* run, the compiler just wants you to know it found some deprecated code.

Answer (score 16):

It's not an error, just a **warning**.

The compiler will still produce a class file and you will be able to run it. However, it's a good idea to address the warning, since using deprecated API could lead to more problems later on.

If you choose to see the warnings, you can do this:

```
javac -Xlint:deprecation FileName.java
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have a deprecation

```
javac -Xlint Filename.java
```

Comment: While this snippet may answer the authors question, you want to expand it a little bit and add some words and maybe documetation to the `-Xlint` keyword. Please edit your answer in that respect (also not, that this question is 5 years old and propably solved. IMHO there is no need to answer such an old question which already has a few answers)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same exception in running a gradlew build.  I discovered that the path included Java 1.7 and my JAVA_HOME variable path had 1.8 specifed.  Once I updated the path to 1.8, the build was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Had the similar issue and setting the PATH to the correct file that contains the JDK worked.
For windows, 
search environnement variables > select edit environnement variables > Enter  JAVA_HOME as variable and set the value to the jdk file.