# How can I do "Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details" on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am developing an app using Flutter on Android Studio.

I have seen warnings like this, but I am not sure how to run `Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details` on Android Studio specifically. Could you give me ideas?

[image: Warnings]

Pages I have checked (but I think they are a bit different from my case):

- [Recompile with -Xlint : unchecked for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54052131/recompile-with-xlint-unchecked-for-details)
- [Deprecated compiling error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239215/deprecated-compiling-error)
- [How to show the compile error's details on Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809306/how-to-show-the-compile-errors-details-on-android-studio)

Comment: can you try with latest version of cloud_firestore =>  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5

Comment: I am using 0.13.5. It may be hard to see, but `.5` is in the second line of the red message.

Answer (score 6):

In your project level build.gradle file add this and build the app again

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    gradle.projectsEvaluated{
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }


}
```

It will show the deprecation warnings.Upgrade them to latest version.Hope this fix your problem